# How to get listcomprehension result as unpacked list

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I have a function (in the example: `some_function()`) that returns a set. I got a data structure of some elements (in the example `arr`) and need to map the elements to the function and I want to get back a set of all elements. Not a set of sets but a set of all the elements that are in the sets. I know that `some_function()` only returns one dimensional sets.

I tried to use `map` but didn't quite get it to work, I got it to work with list comprehensions but I don't really like my solution.

Is it possible to not create a list and then unpack it?
Or can I somehow convert what I get from my `map` approach without much work?

Example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

# I want something like this
set.union(some_function(1), some_function(2), some_function(3))

# where some_function returns a set    

# this is my current solution
set.union(*[some_function(el) for el in arr]))

# approach with map, but I couldn't convert it back to a set
map(some_function, arr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension so that you don't have to create a temporary list first:

```
set.union(*(some_function(el) for el in arr)))
```

or, using `map`:

```
set.union(*map(some_function, arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your current solution is fine. If you want to avoid creating a list, you may try:

```
set.union(*(some_function(el) for el in arr)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, sometimes you just have to not be fancy.

```
result = set()

for el in arr:
    result.update(some_function(el))
```

This approach doesn’t create a list of the return values and so doesn’t hold onto sets longer than necessary. You can wrap it in a function for cleanliness.

Comment: You can use `functools.reduce(set.union, map(some_function, arr))` as well to avoid holding many sets in memory. This also works if you replace the call to `map` with a generator expression like `(some_function(el) for el in arr)`.

Comment: @chepner: That’s O(n²) because it copies the set every time, isn’t it?

Comment: Hmmm, probably.